# pandas time range per day

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a gps data log contained in a pandas data frame. I need to calculate the 'up time' for each day i.e. last recorded point minus first recorded point. What is the best approach here?

```
                     datetime   latitude  longitude  weekday
1     2015-08-25 17:10:53.920  52.232342   0.134956        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `DataFrame` is named `df`, you can do this:

```
def uptime(series):
    return (series.max() - series.min()).total_seconds()

uptime_each_day = df.groupby(
    df.datetime.apply(lambda x: x.date())
).apply(lambda grp: uptime(grp.datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
day_groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='1D'))
day_groups.datetime.max() - day_groups.datetime.min()
```